# Python with..asの後で関数の追記する使い方の意味

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

pandasを使って、sqliteからデータを読み込む例です。

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')

with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    data = pd.read_sql_table('data', conn)
```

with文の基本的な使い方は知っているけど、asの後で関数の呼び出しは見たことないです。このconn.begin()の役割を教えていただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

そう難しい話ではなく, 以下と同等で 後側の `as` がないだけです
(`.begin()` とはなにか？という質問ならトランザクションの開始です)

```py
with engine.connect() as conn:
    with conn.begin():
        pass # なにか処理
```

またこれらは次のようにもできます

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    pass # なにか処理
```

参考: (docs.sqlalchemy.org) [Working with Engines and Connections: Using Transactions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#using-transactions)

Answer (score 2):

With文では、複数のコンテキストマネージャを使えます。それらは入れ子にされたように振舞います。

> 複数の要素があるとき、コンテキストマネージャは複数の with 文がネストされたかのように進行します:
>
> ```
> with A() as a, B() as b:
>     SUITE
> ```
>
> これは次と等価です:
>
> ```
> with A() as a:
>     with B() as b:
>         SUITE
> ```
>
> —— [with 文](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

質問のコードは上の例でいうところの `as b` が省略されたものです。つまり、

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
    with conn.begin():
```

となります。